# Angular: Why doesn't show anything in html page?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-module

This is my heroes.component.html:

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
        <h2>{{hero.name}} Details</h2>
        <div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
        <div><span>name: </span>{{hero.name}}</div>
        <app-heroes></app-heroes>
    </h1>
    <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
```

This is my heroes.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
    
@Component({
    selector: 'app-heroes',
    templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
    hero: Hero = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Windstorm'
    };
    
    constructor() { }
    
    ngOnInit() { }  
}
```

Finally this is my app.module.ts:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeroesComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The browser should refresh and display `HeroesComponent`'s content, but it's showing `AppComponent`'s content. What do I do next to solve my problem?

Comment: So the heroes component displays the heroes component, which displays the heroes component, etc. etc.?

Answer (score 5):

Adding `<app-heroes></app-heroes>` to `app.component.html` should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add your component details in app.module.ts inside bootstrap field like :
bootstrap: [AppComponent, HeroesComponent]